# How to set up SSL on an Apache + Tomcat set ups

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I am trying to set up SSL for my apache + tomcat set up. Both apache http and tomcat support ssl encryption.

I have mode rewrite set up so that http://www.example.com goes to apache while http://www.example.com/web subdomain goes to tomcat.

What is the EASIEST way to set up SSL support? Do i need to install SSL on both apache and tomcat? Or can I just set it up on apache?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the SSL on both the server.
**Note**: you need to use the same private key for both servers. You can use this link to convert your SSL certificate in multiple formats [click here](https://www.https.in/support/ssl-converter)

Use this code to convert the file from PFX to JKS format `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore xyz.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore xyz.jks -deststoretype jks`

Kindly use this article to install SSL on Apache server [click here](https://www.https.in/support/kb/article/24) and this article to install on Tomcat [click here](https://www.https.in/support/kb/article/26)